# How do I set a Bash variable whose value might be empty?

Tags: bash

I'm no Bash expert and I'm puzzled why my code won't work.

With

```
od = `pip list --outdated | cut -d ' ' -f 1`; if [ ${#od} -eq 0 ]; then echo 'Up to date'; else echo 'Outdated stuff!'; echo pip install -U $od; fi
```

I get

```
od: =: No such file or directory
od: =: Bad file descriptor
-bash: 0: command not found
-bash: [: -neq: unary operator expected
```

What am I doing wrong here when I try to set the output of test for a list of the names of out of date packages to a variable?

Comment: http://shellcheck.net is a useful tool.

Comment: `foo = bar` is completely different from `foo=bar`.

Comment: @TomFenech: There goes my day!

Comment: ...if it were otherwise, you'd be unable to pass `=` as the first argument to any command. (Granted, one could add *even more* special cases to the syntax to work around that, requiring quotes or such... but shell has enough special case rules as it is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put space around the = operator in assignments.

```
od=`pip list --outdated | cut -d ' ' -f 1`; if [ ${#od} -eq 0 ]; then echo 'Up to date'; else echo 'Outdated stuff!'; echo pip install -U $od; fi
```

Also, don't use back ticks, wrap sub shells in `$(...)` instead:

```
od=$(pip list --outdated | cut -d ' ' -f 1); if [ ${#od} -eq 0 ]; then echo 'Up to date'; else echo 'Outdated stuff!'; echo pip install -U $od; fi
```

Finally, a simpler way of checking if the value of `od` is empty:

```
if [ ! "$od" ]; then ...
```

So that gives:

```
od=$(pip list --outdated | cut -d ' ' -f 1); if [ ! "$od" ]; then echo 'Up to date'; else echo 'Outdated stuff!'; echo pip install -U $od; fi
```

Comment: Looks good. I might use `read -a` or similar to actually use an array rather than counting on string-splitting to do the right thing, but there's an argument to be made that that's quibbling over corner cases (like non-default IFS values) that aren't particularly likely.

Comment: Heh. I'm actually not a fan of using the implicit `-n` argument to test, simply because there's a chance of the data being tested looking like test command syntax. Granted, the really nasty cases of that only come in when using `-a` or `-o` (hence their being deprecated in the current POSIX standard), and the worst one can really get in two-argument usage like this is a harmless error going to stderr and a correct (falsey) exit status, but... *shrug*.

Answer (score 0):

```
od=`pip list --outdated | cut -d ' ' -f 1`; if [ ${#od} -eq 0 ]; then echo 'Up to date'; else echo 'Outdated stuff!'; echo pip install -U $od; fi
```

Get rid of the spaces around the `=`